# How to merge res.partner objects programmatically in odoo-10?

Tags: merge, odoo, crm, odoo-10

I'm trying to merge some partners inside a server action programmatically  without using "Merge Selected Partners" (which is provided by odoo itself and must select some partners do some clicks and then merge).
To do so , I used `base.partner.merge.automatic.wizard` model object with two fields set ,`partner_ids` and `dst_partner_id` then called `action_merge()` method on it.
This is what i've tried so far in many faces, but its not working and I get no errors.

```py
    partner_ids = env['res.partner'].browse([3135,5379])
    dst_partner = env['res.partner'].browse(5379)
    merge = env['base.partner.merge.automatic.wizard'].create({
        'partner_ids': partner_ids,
        'dst_partner_id': dst_partner[0].id,
    })
    merge.action_merge()
```

(For testing purpose 2 static ids were selected)

[MergePartnerAutomatic(model.TransientModel)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/crm/wizard/base_partner_merge.py) source code on github.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: a One2many field uses a special syntax. So, use `'partner_ids': [(6,0,partner_ids.ids)],`

```
partner_ids = env['res.partner'].browse([3135,5379])
dst_partner = env['res.partner'].browse(5379)
merge = env['base.partner.merge.automatic.wizard'].create({
    'partner_ids': [(6,0,partner_ids.ids)],
    'dst_partner_id': dst_partner[0].id,
})
merge.action_merge()
```

**Long answer:**

One2many and Many2many use a special “commands” format to manipulate the set of records stored in/associated with the field.

This format is a list of triplets executed sequentially, where each triplet is a command to execute on the set of records. Not all commands apply in all situations. Possible commands are:

- (0, _, values)
  adds a new record created from the provided value dict.
- (1, id, values)
  updates an existing record of id id with the values in values. Can not be used in create().
- (2, id, _)
  removes the record of id id from the set, then deletes it (from the database). Can not be used in create().
- (3, id, _)
  removes the record of id id from the set, but does not delete it. Can not be used on One2many. Can not be used in create().
- (4, id, _)
  adds an existing record of id id to the set. Can not be used on One2many.
- (5, _, _)
  removes all records from the set, equivalent to using the command 3 on every record explicitly. Can not be used on One2many. Can not be used in create().
- (6, _, ids)
  replaces all existing records in the set by the ids list, equivalent to using the command 5 followed by a command 4 for each id in ids.
  Values marked as _ in the list above are ignored and can be anything, generally 0 or False.

Reference: Odoo ORM API documentation at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#relational-fields

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko `'partner_ids': partner_ids.ids,` vs `'partner_ids': partner_ids,` @AdanCortes [edit] your answer and add some explanation